# Angular2 Observables map and subscribe at once?

Tags: angular, dictionary, observable, subscribe

I got a function that subscribes to an observable like this:

```
public whatever(): Observable<Response> {
  this.someService.functionReturnsObservable(params)
    .subscribe(
      success => {
        /* stuff to be done after observable's next */
      }
    );

  return this.someService.functionReturnsObservable(params)
    .maps((response: Response) => response));
}
```

This way I call the function twice. I tried something like

```
public whatever(): Observable<Response> {
  return this.someService.functionReturnsObservable(params)
    .map((response: Response) => { 
      /* whatever I put here, even console.log(smthg) does not work */
    });
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I have the feeling that you're looking for the do() operator, which allows doing something every time an event is emitted, and propagate the event as is, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An observable only runs if it is subscribed to. If it returns a `.map`, but nothing subscribes to it, it will never run the `.map`. Try subscribing to the result of the `map`.

```
public whatever(): Observable<Response> {
  let returnObs = this.someService.functionReturnsObservable(params)
    .map((response: Response) => { 
      console.log('map');
    });

  returnObs.subscribe((response) => {
      console.log('subscribe');
    });

  return returnObs;
}
```